# Caption tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions

I am getting an out of float error, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}    

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                ,xlabel=$N$
                ,ylabel=speedup
                ,axis x line=bottom
                ,axis y line=left
                ]
                \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(755,1.4) (1978, 1.6) (6273, 1.8) (12222, 2.1)};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
% Where to put the caption?
%\caption{\label{plot:speedup}Speedup of distributed execution, versus serial. N is the leading dimension of the matrix.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you need here is `title` not a `caption`.

Comment: Can you provide an example @salimbou in an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get an `out of float error` because you used a `\caption` out side the float environment known as `figure`. A `\caption` can only be inserted between `\begin{<float environment>} ... \end{<float environment>}`.

Put the `\caption` after the end of `tikzpicture`, directly after the `\end{tikzpicture}` line. Also, use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center} ... \begin{center}` inside float environments to get consistent spacing around floats. Finally, for readability purposes, drop the `\label` on a separate line after `\caption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}    
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[%
            ,xlabel=$N$
            ,ylabel=speedup
            ,axis x line=bottom
            ,axis y line=left
            ]
            \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(755,1.4) (1978, 1.6) (6273, 1.8) (12222, 2.1)};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Speedup of distributed execution, versus serial. N is the leading dimension of the matrix.}
\label{plot:speedup}
\end{figure}

As we see in figure \ref{plot:speedup} ...

\end{document}
```

Another option if you don't like the `figure` environment is to use `\captionof{<float>}` from the `caption` package. You will get the same result.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,caption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                ,xlabel=$N$
                ,ylabel=speedup
                ,axis x line=bottom
                ,axis y line=left
                ]
                \addplot[very thick] coordinates {(755,1.4) (1978, 1.6) (6273, 1.8) (12222, 2.1)};
            \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{Speedup of distributed execution, versus serial. N is the leading dimension of the matrix.}
\label{plot:speedup}
\end{center}

As we see in figure \ref{plot:speedup} ...

\end{document}
```